# Trying to create white image using numpy arrays, buts displays as black

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am trying to create a white canvas using numpy arrays. I am using the below set of codes. Also, attaching the result of the code.

```
canvas = np.zeros((300, 300), np.uint8)
canvas_1 = 255 - canvas

plt.imshow(canvas_1,cmap = 'gray',  interpolation = 'none')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```

the plt.show is showing a black image

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imwhow scales the image given to the range 0..1 internally. If your image only contains values 255, it is mapped to 0.

So in your case you need to specify a fixed range of 0-255:

```
canvas = np.zeros((300, 300), np.uint8)
canvas_1 = 255 - canvas

plt.imshow(canvas_1,cmap = 'gray',  interpolation = 'none', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```